# Cell number and IMEI details

Tags: physical

Is there a device I can install to collect cell number and IMEI numbers for people within a vicinity?

We want to install in an area for security reasons so that we are able to trace the people in the event of a break in. Currently we have cameras and movement sensors which is not very helpful as our reaction time is known hence thieves have gone in and out before we catch them in the act.

This will be used in a small private area about 1000 m<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

These devices are called IMSI Catchers, and are in use by state agencies and law enforcement entities. I doubt whether you can get such a device for private surveillance.

I also doubt whether you will succeed preventing theft with such a device. A sopisticated thief will not carry HIS mobile around.

Comment: Not to mention it would be highly immoral and probably illegal.

Comment: But not for the police at legal demonstrations, right?